# Smooth auto scrolling to bottom JavaScript when zoomed in

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, smooth-scrolling

I am using WebBrowser control to develop a browser app for Windows phone. I am trying to implement auto scroll to the bottom using the following code. It works fine but when the page is zoomed in `document.body.scrollHeight` in the the conditional check

`if (document.body.scrollHeight > (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight))`

is always larger causing the function to be called non stop and the terminating `clearTimeout(timeOutDown)` is never reached.

```
var timeOutDown;
function scrollToBottom() 
{ 
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    if (document.body.scrollHeight > (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight))
    {
         window.scrollBy(0, 100); 
         window.external.notify(String(window.innerHeight));
         timeOutDown=setTimeout('scrollToBottom()',10);
    }
     else 
    {
        clearTimeout(timeOutDown);
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this considering user can zoom in/out the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, just replace `document.documentElement.scrollTop` with `window.pageYOffset`. So the conditional statement becomes

`if (document.body.scrollHeight > (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight))`

This will take care of the zoom factor.

Comment: Accepting your own answer isn't taboo! You get no rep for it. When you do so, future visitors get a clear understanding that this was the correct answer right off the bat.